# Greasemonkey remove string from url without regex

Tags: javascript, string, url, greasemonkey

If I have a webpage with referral strings on every URL which I want to remove with greasemonkey, How can I do that?

For example:

```
<a href="https://website.refer?url=www.google.com"> The link </a>
```

[The link](https://website.refer?url=www.google.com)

Changed to:

```
<a href="www.google.com"> The link </a>
```

[The link](https://www.google.com)

How can I remove the "/website.refer?url=" part of the URL?

I've tried things such as:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a").replace('/website.refer?url=','');
```

Yet nothing I try seems to work See fiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/oagd0qnj/1/)

Please no regex. Thanks

Comment: Note that `<a href="www.google.com"> The link </a>` will link you to an *internal* page with that path, which is almost certainly not what you want. You probably want an external link instead - prepend a protocol or `//` to the `href` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over every `<a>`, get the `url` parameter via URLSearchParameters, and assign it to the `href` of the `<a>`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((a) => {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(a.href.split('?')[1]);
  a.href = '//' + params.get('url');
});
```

```html
<a href="https://website.refer.com?url=www.google.com"> The link </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName` will return live `HTMLCollection` and replace works with `strings`.

Instead you can get the `href` attribute of each `a` tag and use replace on it.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a => {
  const newHref = a.getAttribute('href').replace('//website.refer?url=', '');
  a.href = newHref;
});
```

```html
  <a href="https://website.refer?url=www.google.com"> Link 1 </a>
```